# Refreshing browser web-page not load in ui-router when locationProvider used

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, location-provider

When I directly refresh the browser using F5 or directly hitting the url,
page not load but when I click on the button then the page gets load

I am using like this

Enable HTML5Mode using $locationProvider

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngCookies']);
routerApp.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true
    })
});
```

I Added the following code to the  of your HTML file:

```
<base href="/">
```

or Simply using Syntax like that

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
    })
```

I find that this is already issue on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/105

Can someone knows how to solve this ?
When I am not using $locationProvider for omitting '#' then it is working fine with refreshing too

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to omit #? Why  not just keep the prefix?

Comment: as per the requirement, need to omit # from the url

Answer (score 1):

Attempt this

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
})
```

Comment: Also tried that too but it didn't work and now I write in question too

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
})
```

Comment: Also tried that too but it didn't work and now I write in question too